# Code doesn't display correctly

Tags: bug, specific-question, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serverfault cut off/truncated on long post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post)

The code in the top post at "Factorial Algorithms in different languages" on Stack Overflow, ["Polyglot: 5 languages, all using bignums"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930/factorial-algorithms-in-different-languages/441229#441229), doesn't display correctly and hasn't displayed correctly for some time.  In particular, it gets cut off after some point, but it's not clear to me what causes this break.

The source is absolutely ridiculous (it's a polyglot as the name indicates, and it gets cut off in the middle of some brainf*** code), but it should still display correctly.  In fact, if you look at the revision history, or try editing the post, it does display correctly.

Technical note: the post currently uses `<pre>` tags because previously the `<code>` tag broke the Whitespace.  In theory I'm open to using `<code>` tags but it should work either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [been noted before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post) and all that you can do to clear it up is just add some extra spaces at the end of the post with the next edit. That pretty much fixes it.

Comment: Ok, random fixed it.

Comment: Well, the extra spaces would probably fix the problem, but now it's broken again because `<code>` tags break the Whitespace.  =(

Comment: Okay, I went back to `<pre>` tags, so it's no longer truncated but Whitespace still works.  Thanks for everyone's help!